# "Workforce" - but with a more white-collar connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm asking for exactly what I stated in my title. The problem with "workforce" is that it denotes a blue-collar, manual labor kind of image. Is there a similar single noun word that might infer more white-collar-like image?

Sample: "I'm looking to re-enter the *workforce* again very soon!"

Comment: I think *workforce* doesn't really have a *blue collar* connotation for everyone.  And it can always be modified with *white-collar* if necessary.  For your sample sentence why not be a bit more explicit: *I'm looking to re-enter the <engineering> workforce*  or whatever.

Comment: @henchmanjustin Why do you think that "workforce" denotes a blue-collar, manual labor kind of image?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative might be: "I'm looking to resume a profession." As said in the comments, though, the "workforce" is not limited to blue-collar work. It applies to the whole spectrum of employees. Blue-collar workers might be referred to as something like the "manual workforce" to distinguish them.

Comment: Does it include pink and green collar workers too? Or grey-collar workers? How about gold-collar?

Comment: All collars—except dog collars.

Answer (score 1):

> ***[Workforce](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/workforce)*** definition actually includes all kinds of workers.
>
> - All the people working or available to work, as in a nation, company, industry, or on a project. (AHD)

If you want to be more specific you may refer to ***[professional workforce](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=professional%20workforce&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprofessional%20workforce%3B%2Cc0)***.